# On the boundedness of the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**My question:**

Let $A\neq 0$ and $D\neq 0$ be constant real matrices of size $n \times n$ and define $M(z) = D + z A$.

Is it possible for the eigenvalues of $M(z)$ to be bounded (in absolute value) by 1, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(z)<0$?

**My attempt:**

I proved the answer is no for the case $n=2$, as we can take $z=x\in\mathbb{R}$, find the eigenvalues using the quadratic formula and show that they are unbounded as $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

This method however does not generalize to $n\geq 5$ for example.

**Some background on where this question came from:**

I am investigating the region of stability of block methods for ODEs. It is a well known fact that no explicit method can be A-stable, and thus the answer to the above question should be no. The proof for multistep/multistage methods is rather simple, but I got stuck when trying to prove it for my case. I also looked in books on numerical analysis that cover block methods (such as Butcher's book on general linear methods) but could not find the proof of this.

I do have a feeling that the proof is simple and I am just overlooking something.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of $M$, which is the trace of $D$ plus $z$ times the trace of $A$. Unless the trace of $A$ is zero, the trace of $M$ is unbounded, so the eigenvalues can't be bounded in absolute value.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Brilliant! How could I have missed that. Any thoughts about the case where the trace of $A$ is zero?

Comment: Then the eigenvalues can be bounded. Take $D$ to be a multiple of the identity matrix and $A$ nilpotent.

Comment: @Tzimmo Thanks!